# How to map radio buttons to a specific number?

Tags: javascript, grid

I'm trying to map radio button to a specific number . Say I have radio button with different numbers  X - 1 2 3 4 5 . If I select third radio button, after saving it should have 3 or whatever number stored in the database. I thought of using if else if there are 100 such radio buttons, it can be a problem.

Comment: you should add more details to your question. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: You need to post actual code; it's quite unclear what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g7xdmytq/

```
<div class="radio-wrapper">
    <input name="number" type="radio" value="1" />
    <input name="number" type="radio" value="2" />
    <input name="number" type="radio" value="3" />
    <input name="number" type="radio" value="4" />
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.radio-wrapper').on('click', 'input[type="radio"]', function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        //save it to backend
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
</script>
```

Just change alert to AJAX request to your backend.